# CopyPixels method in Bgr32 format

Tags: bitmapsource, getpixel

i'm just doing a simple job: Converting a bitmap into an array, then using that array, recreating the bitmap with BitmapSource.Create method.

However, i'm getting the error: "Value does not fall within the expected range". Here's my code.

```
        Dim width As Integer = bitmapImage.PixelWidth
        Dim height As Integer = bitmapImage.PixelHeight
        Dim bytesPerPixel As Integer = bitmapImage.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8
        Dim stride As Integer = width * bytesPerPixel

        Dim pixelBuffer = New Byte(height * stride - 1) {}
        bitmapImage.CopyPixels(pixelBuffer, stride, 0)

        Dim bmpSource As BitmapSource = BitmapSource.Create(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, Nothing, pixelBuffer, width)
        Image2.Source = bmpSource
```

Any help regarding that will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Because stride is the count of bytes in one scanline, which is BytesPerPixel x Width. Then total bytes are stride x height, as I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dim pixelBuffer = New Byte(height * stride - 1) {}` allocates one byte too little.

As an example, a 4x4 pixel image with 4 bytes per pixel will allocate 4*4*4-1=63 bytes, but 64 are required.

Also, you're using BGR32 (4 byte pixels) here so you're safe, but the stride may in other pixel formats need to be rounded up to the next 4 byte boundary.

BitmapSource.Create also takes `stride` as last parameter, not `width`.

Comment: I tried 63, 64, 65, and even 66 with a 4x4 pixel image. I still get the same error, I think that may not be related to the array length.

Comment: @BurakYavuzalp Try changing the last parameter of BitmapSource.Create to `stride` too.